# Как организовать, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку выплывала форма заявки?

Tags: html, css

Помогите разобраться.

Картинка

```
<!-- MENU --> ".s_browse_level(0, $browse_sub[2])." <div class='MENU'>".($browse_sub[2]==$sub ? "<img src='$SUB_FOLDER/images/template/knopka.png' alt='Кнопка' />" : "<a href='$SUB_FOLDER/'><img src='$SUB_FOLDER/images/template/knopka.png' alt='Кнопка' /></a>")."</div><!-- End MENU -->
```

И вот это, например, должно всплывать)

```
Отправить заявку: <p><select> <option>услуги</option> </select> </p> <p><input value='имя'> </p> <p><input value='сайт'> </p> <p><input value='телефон'> </p> <p><textarea>текст сообщения</textarea></p> </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Всплывающие окна](http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html)

Comment: Спасибо, только ещё не совсем понять могу, ошибки выдаются)

Answer (score 0):

[Всплывающие окна на Jquery](http://takein.ru/jquery/42-vsplyvayuschie-okna-na-jquery.html)